# How to call a method of another contract with given value?

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation

How to call a method in another contract with given value?

```
contract A {
  function f(int256 a, string b) { ... }
}
```

How to call `A.f` from another contract `B` with say 0.5 ETH value (if `B` was called with say 1 ETH value)?

Comment: `a.f.value(500000000000000000)(6, 7);`

Comment: `a.f.value(500000000000000000)(6, "7");` to be more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Note: Function `f` must be **payable** to receive *Wei*.

Comment: While this is true, it does not answer the question.

Comment: @goodvibration You have already answered the question in the comments, this was an addition to your answer. I unfortunately can not add comments yet...

Comment: Oh... got it :)